# Does file_get_contents() use a cache?

Tags: php, http, file-get-contents

If I write:

```
 $mypage=file_get_contents("www.mywebsite.com/mypage.htm");
```

The first time I run the script, file_get_contents() will surely make a HTTP request to www.mywebsite.com for mypage.htm, and get a response with the content of mypage.htm.

But every next time I run the script, will file_get_contents() get the real file on www.mywebsite.com?
Or it has some kind of cache on the localhost?

Comment: No it doesn't but you might use db, apc or memcached to handle the cache yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does **not**. However, there will be a speed-up because the **DNS resolution** step may be faster on subsequent tries (till the cached entry expires), as the DNS records are cached by the server's OS.